# How to obtain the data in this format

Tags: reactjs, string, dictionary, redux, split

Demo Question 1,Demo Question 2,Demo Question 3: "Answer 2,Answer 2,Answer 4"

I need to get this data as below format

Demo Question 1:Answer 2,
Demo Question 2:Answer 2,
Demo Question 3:Answer 4

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are these strings or json?

Comment: string obtained on parsing the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each question will have the answer

```js
function formatData(string) {
       const [q, a] = string.split(':');
       const ques = q.split(',');
       const ans = a.split(',');
       const obj = {};
    
       for (let i = 0; i < ques.length; i++) {
         obj[ques[i]] = ans[i].replace("\"", '').trim();
       }
       
       console.log(obj);
       return obj;
    }

    formatData('Demo Question 1,Demo Question 2,Demo Question 3: "Answer 2,Answer 2,Answer 4"');
```

Comment: const columnData = []
                data[i].questions.map((questionHeader => {
                    let columnQuestionOption = {}
                    columnQuestionOption[questionHeader.question] = questionHeader.question_option
                    columnData.push(columnQuestionOption)
                }))
                columnData.map(item => {
                    data[i][Object.keys(item).toString()] = Object.values(item).toString()
                })
            }